# Magento 2 parent theme behavior

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, frontend

we have a complex shop structure with an multishop base theme from scratch and about 10 child themes.

The structure is as follows:

- multishop_theme/
  default (main theme content)
  child theme 1 (other css, layout ...)
  child theme 2
  child theme 3,4,5,6,7 and so on

Now we want to add other shops that are not based on our multishop_theme but we want to share some defaults (payment templates, customer, checkout), so that we dont repeat ourselves. What is the best structure in this case?

- multishop_theme/
  default
  child
  child
- default/default
- singleshop_themes/
  theme 1
  theme 2

So the multishop_theme/default is based on default/default, and the multishop childs are based on multishop_theme/default.

The new shops are based on default/default too. What do you recommend?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I ask myself one question, why you create one theme for each store ? if the purpose is to have a different design, you can create a different css per storeview like this: `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/i18n/en_US/css/style.css`, `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/i18n/fr_FR/css/style.css` etc...

How ever if the purpose is to change completely the `design`, `layout`, `templates`, `rootcategories per store`, in this case I understand why stores, storeviews.

So I thing there no other solution except create different themes-childs exemple :

```
app/design/frontend/Luma/luma-child1
                     |___luma-child2
                     |___luma-child3

app/design/frontend/Blank/blank-child1
                     |____blank-child2
                     |____blank-child3
```

Comment: Yes there are different styles, layouts, templates and so on. It's all from scratch and each shop has a different and for its use optimized structure except for things like layered navigation, pagination, checkout, customer etc.. We want to use multi parent system to share that including payment modules, self created modules and so on.<br/>
My question is what is the best practice in M2? Is it possible to use another Vendor/Child (default/default for instance) as a default parent theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can create new theme inside multishop_theme set parent theme as luma or blank whatever you want to use it.

multishop_theme/

- default
- child
- child
- singleshop_themes (Newly created theme).

Copy and paste modules according to your requirement from your base theme to singleshop theme.

I hop it will help you.